# problem with rails instalation need 2.3.8 after installation still getting "rails -v" = "Rails 2.3.5"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to setup clockingit but...

even after 
gem install -v=2.3.8 rails
1 gem installed

i'm getting

rails -v
Rails 2.3.5

I need 2.3.8 to rake the gems for clockingit
help greatly apreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try `gem install -v 2.3.8 rails` (no equal sign). You should also check if the version of Ruby on Rails installed through RubyGems is used at all. Maybe a version of Ruby on Rails installed through the package management of your operating system overlaps the version installed through RubyGems.

Comment: without the equal sign made no difference. Yes i believe the operating sys version is overriding the gem version. So how do you specify the gem version of rails (or path to) so that rake can find it?

the problem stems from 
rake gems (in clockingit)

giving
 
<code>
Missing the Rails 2.3.8 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.8 rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.
</code>

Answer (score 0):

Try to [use rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/). It is dead simple to deal with, and makes managing gems very easy. If you already on rvm, try to create another gemset
    rvm gemset create new_gemset
and the try to install rails